# Is the map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \{\vec 0 \}$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Not quite sure how you search for these, so please close if duplicate.

Given a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \{\vec{0}\}$, we have

$T(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha T(x) + \beta T(y) = \vec{0}$, which seems to show that it is a linear map.

It seems really weird though, so I was wondering if this is actually a linear map or I'm missing some extra condition.

Comment: It's linear all right. Not the most exciting of linear transformations, but needed to complete the picture. Without the constant map to $\vec{0}$ the linear transformation would not form a vector space themselves, but I'm not sure you have defined an abstract vector space yet, so this last sentence may be Greek to you.

Comment: You can write $T(x) = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix} x$. Any map of the form $x \mapsto Ax$ is linear.